# MySQL - replacing subquery with something more efficient

Tags: mysql

I am trying to display a list of customers along with the number of orders they have placed as well as the date of their last order. Some customers may have placed no orders.

I am filtering the customers by their registration date, at the moment I am only interested in recently registered customers. I think my current query is running subqueries for all customers first and then performing the WHERE look up.

How can I make this query more efficient?

```
select 
customers.*, 
addresses.*,
(select count(*) from orders where customerID=customers.customerID) orders,
(select orderDate from orders where customerID=customers.customerID order by orderID desc     limit 1) lastOrder                    
from customers 
left join addresses on customers.defaultCollection=addresses.addressID 
where 
registrationDate >= '2014-02-04'
```

Comment: Why don't you transfer the subqueries to the WHERE-part?

Comment: @Mainz007 How could that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query, with table aliases on every column to clearly identify where they come from (I hope I get them right):

```
select c.*, a.*,
       (select count(*) 
        from orders o
        where o.customerID = c.customerID
       ) as orders,
       (select o.orderDate
        from orders o
        where o.customerID = c.customerID
        order by o.orderID desc
        limit 1
       ) as lastOrder                    
from customers c left join
     addresses a
     on c.defaultCollection = a.addressID 
where c.registrationDate >= '2014-02-04' ;
```

The query is not necessarily bad.  It would benefit from having some indexes:  `customers(registrationDate, defaultCollection, CustomerId)`, `addresses(addressId)`, and most importantly `orders(CustomerID, orderId, orderDate)`.  These indexes might be sufficient for reaching the performance you want.

In fact, turning this into an aggregation query may not help, because you have to add an aggregation:

```
select c.*, a.*, count(o.customerId) as numOrders,
       substring_index(group_concat(o.OrderDate order by o.OrderId desc), ',', 1) as LastOrderIdOrderDate
from customers c left join
     addresses a
     on c.defaultCollection = a.addressID left join
     orders o
     on o.customerId = c.customerId
where c.registrationDate >= '2014-02-04'
group by c.customerId, a.AddressId;
```

The `substring_index()` expression is to do what you have in the question -- get the date of the biggest `orderId`.  If this is the maximum order date, then a better expression is `max(o.OrderDate)`.

Comment: Thank you for this - I have indexes on the individual columns that you have mentioned. What I don't have is a single index that covers multiple columns. Would you recommend this? I have never done this before

Comment: @user1698575 . . . Yes!  This query needs composite indexes, particularly on the `orders` table.

Answer (score 0):

is this efficient ?

```
 select 
 c.*, 
 a.*,
 count(*) ,
 max(orderDate) as  lastOrder
 from customers c 
 left join addresses a 
 on c.defaultCollection=a.addressID 
 left join orders o 
 on o.customerID=c.customerID
 where 
 registrationDate >= '2014-02-04' 
 group by o.customerID
```

Comment: Beside the question if it is effective, it will return exactly one more or less random row. GROUP BY is missing...

Comment: And you need a left join for the case that no orders exist for the customer

Comment: This returns the maximum of the order date, rather than the date of the order with the highest id.  That may or may not be the same.

Comment: @echo_Me - this is giving me "You have an error in your SQL syntax"

Comment: @user1698575 you just gave me half error :)! give the whole error pls

Comment: @echo_Me Here you go ... "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) , max(orderDate) as lastOrder from customers c left join addresses a ' at line 4"

Comment: @echo_Me Thanks, that's good .. but it only shows customers with orders. It doesn't show those unfortunate people who have yet to place an order

Comment: @user1698575 as i already wrote, you need a left join, not an inner join on the table orders